# Order rows based on date and time contained in a string in SQL

Tags: sql, string, dataframe, datetime

I query a database in SQL and I pull the results into a data frame with 2 columns ID and ImagePath. ID contains bunch of IDs int type. ImagePath looks like this: Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-21_13-33-02_COLOR_ID_139.jpg.
This column has bunch of those image paths. What is different in each of the row? Date and Color ID. I am interested in ordering those based on date and time from inside. What I am doing at the moment I am using a dataframe:

```
 self.df = self.df.reset_index(drop=True)
 idx = self.df['ImagePath'].str[45:].str[:11].sort_values().index
 self.df = self.df.reindex(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This works just fine. This data comes from a database, I do a query and pull the results into a dataframe and then do this. I want to optimize this, and I wonder if it is possible to do this without dataframes and do it through the query directly.

Comment: Do you have more samples of other `ImagePath` values? Would be useful to find a common pattern

Comment: Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-21_13-33-02_COLOR_ID_143.jpg // Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-22_14-53-12_COLOR_ID_148.jpg // Images/Machine/M278_A1_2022-09-22_14-57-42_COLOR_ID_149.jpg

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL with its own string- and date- handling functions. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by extracting the part of the image path with the timestamp using a regexp, then cleaning it up a bit, and finally converting it into a timestamp type:

```sql
with dummy_data as (
    select 'Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-21_13-33-02_COLOR_ID_143.jpg' as imagepath
    union all
    select 'Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-22_14-53-12_COLOR_ID_148.jpg'
    union all
    select 'Images/Machine/M278_A1_2022-09-22_14-57-42_COLOR_ID_149.jpg'
)

select 
    imagepath,
    to_timestamp(replace(regexp_substr(imagepath, '([0-9]+[-][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[_][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[-][0-9]+)'), '_', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS') as image_timestamp
from dummy_data
order by image_timestamp;
```

**Output:**

| IMAGEPATH | IMAGE_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-21_13-33-02_COLOR_ID_143.jpg | 2022-09-21 13:33:02.000 |
| Images/Machine/M278_A2_2022-09-22_14-53-12_COLOR_ID_148.jpg | 2022-09-22 14:53:12.000 |
| Images/Machine/M278_A1_2022-09-22_14-57-42_COLOR_ID_149.jpg | 2022-09-22 14:57:42.000 |

Disclaimer: this is using Snowflake SQL, can adjust to another lingo if needed